# Breaks between pages MS Word

Tags: ms-word

Does anyone know why the pages have been setup like this? Using Word 2016

[image]

There's no padding after the next page for the headers. Print preview shows everything as normal like previous versions of Word

Comment: This is not a programming related question. So, I flagged this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a line separates pages. Go over it (by mouse!) and double click when your mouse pointer changed...